# What is the difference between TextFormField and TextField?

Tags: flutter

I am new to Flutter (and Dart) and when trying to build a form to edit an object I searched online for examples and tutorials, and I saw both of these used.

What is the difference between the two? Which one should I use?

Answer (score 126, accepted):

> If you making a `Form` where you require save, reset, or validate
> operations- use `TextFormField`. Else For Simple user input capture
> `TextField` is sufficient.

**`TextFormField`, which integrates with the `Form` widget.**

This is a convenience widget that wraps a TextField widget in a FormField.

A `Form` ancestor is not required. The Form simply makes it easier to *save, reset, or validate multiple fields at once*.

To use without a Form, pass a GlobalKey to the constructor and use GlobalKey.currentState to save or reset the form field.

sample:

```
TextFormField(
  autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.always
  decoration: const InputDecoration(
    icon: Icon(Icons.person),
    hintText: 'What do people call you?',
    labelText: 'Name *',
  ),
  onSaved: (String value) {
    // This optional block of code can be used to run
    // code when the user saves the form.
  },
  validator: (String value) {
    return value.contains('@') ? 'Do not use the @ char.' : null;
  },
)
```

**`TextField`, which is the underlying text field without the `Form` integration.**

The text field calls the `onChanged` callback whenever the user changes the text in the field. If the user indicates that they are done typing in the field (e.g., by pressing a button on the soft keyboard), the text field calls the `onSubmitted` callback.

Comment: This answer is the example shown in the docs here: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextFormField-class.html

Answer (score 45):

### Short answer

If you don't know what you need, then use a `TextField`. This is the most basic Flutter widget for getting text input from a user. It's the one you should master first.

### TextField

Using a `TextField` is an easy way to allow user input.

```
TextField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    hintText: 'Name'
  ),
);
```

[image]

To get the text that the user entered, you can either get notified every time there is a change like this:

```
TextField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
      hintText: 'Name'
  ),
  onChanged: (text) {
    // do something with text
  },
),
```

Or you can use a `TextEditingController`, as described [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/text-field-changes). This will give you access to the text state.

### TextFormField

If you find yourself needing to validate user text input before you save it, you might consider using a `TextFormField`. Imagine something like this:

[image]

There are lots of validation checks that you might want to do on a username and password.

Of course, you could still just use a couple TextFields, but `TextFormField` has extra builtin functionality that will make your life easier. Generally, you will only use a `TextFormField` when you are using it inside of a `Form` widget (though that isn't a strict requirement).

Here is a stripped down example from the [documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/validation):

```
class MyCustomForm extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MyCustomFormState createState() {
    return MyCustomFormState();
  }
}

class MyCustomFormState extends State<MyCustomForm> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          TextFormField(
            validator: (value) {
              // validation logic
            },
          ),
          RaisedButton(
            child: Text('Submit'),
            onPressed: () {
              if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                // text in form is valid
              }
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

### See also

- [Realistic Forms in Flutter — Part 1](https://medium.com/flutter-community/realistic-forms-in-flutter-part-1-327929dfd6fd)
- [Forms with Flutter](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W3rilPv69lM)

Answer (score 21):

## `TextFormField` vs. `TextField`

`TextFormField` returns a `TextField`, but wraps the `TextField` with extra functionality you can use through a `Form` and also without (such as reset, validation, save, etc.).

Generally, you want to use `TextFormField` unless writing boiler-plate code is your thing.

#### How does `TextFormField` work? What can it do?

`TextFormField` extends `FormField` class, (a `StatefulWidget`).
`FormField` objects do a special thing when they are instantiated: **they look up the widget tree for a `Form` and register themselves with that `Form`.**

After registration, these `FormField` widgets can be changed by that parent `Form`.

`Form` is also a `StatefulWidget`. It has a `FormState` object.
`FormState` can get & set data on any/all`FormFields` registered to it.

For example to clear the entire form we can call `reset()` on `FormState` and `FormState` will iterate through all child `FormFields` registered, resetting each `FormField` to its `initialValue` (null by default).

Validation is another common use case for putting several `FormField` like `TextFormField` inside   `Form`/`FormState`.  This allows multiple fields to be validated with a single `validate()` call on the `Form`.

How?  `FormState` has a `validate()` method that iterates through each registered `FormField` and calls that `FormField's` `validate()` method.   Much more convenient calling `validate()` once on `Form` than you manually keeping track of all `TextField` and validating each one separately with custom code.

## Details

#### How does a TextFormField register itself with a Form?

`FormField` (base class of `TextFormField`, etc.) make a call within their `build()` method:
`Form.of(context)?._register(this);`

In English this means:
*Search up my context hierarchy until we find a `Form` widget (if any) and call that form's register method on myself.*

The `?` is in case there is no `Form` widget parent.  The `_register` call will only be run *if* there **is** a `Form` & `FormState` somewhere above.

#### How does `Form.of(context)?._register(this)` work?

`Form` & `FormState` sneakily use `InheritedWidget`.
In `FormState`.build() you'll see this code:

```
return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: widget.onWillPop,
      child: _FormScope( // ← sneaky
        formState: this,
        generation: _generation,
        child: widget.child,
      ),
    );
```

Looking at `_FormScope` we see:

```
class _FormScope extends InheritedWidget
```

When a parent widget is an `InheritedWidget`, any child can find that parent using a special *"find me a parent of this exact Type"* method.

Here's how that "find me" method is used/exposed inside `Form` as a static method we can call from anywhere:

```
static FormState of(BuildContext context) {
    final _FormScope scope = context.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<_FormScope>();
    return scope?._formState;
  }
```

The naming of that method `dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType` is a bit tricky.  It'd be more readable as `findInheritedWidgetOfExactType`, but it does more than just find. (We can trigger rebuilds of `Form` through children that have registered as `dependOn` this `FormState`).

#### Summary

`TextFormField` is the deluxe package, air-conditioned, Bluetooth-connected 8-speaker stereo version of `TextField`.  It includes a lot of common functionality you would use when accepting user-entered information.

Comment: I like this explanation better

Answer (score 19):

`TextField` is a simple text field. (you don't care about user input)
`TextFormField` is a text field to be used in a form (you care about user input).

If you don't need to validate `TextField`.
If you need to validate user input, use TextFormField with `validator`.

Comment: "(you don't care about user input)" of course we care :D it's just not part of a form.

Comment: We always care for user input because that is a factor in app success!

Answer (score 9):

I think this might be the most concise and simple explanation about the differences between the two.

From the [material library](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/material-library.html):

> `TextField`: A material design text field.

> `TextFormField`: A `FormField` that contains a `TextField`.

Similarly, you can wrap `FormField` around any cupertino input component such as `CupertinoTextField`

Below is an example about a custom `CheckboxFormField`, which is a `FormField` that wraps around the material design component `Checkbox`:

```dart
// A custom CheckboxFormField, which is similar to the built-in TextFormField
bool agreedToTerms = false;
FormField(
  initialValue: false,
  validator: (value) {
    if (value == false) {
      return 'You must agree to the terms of service.';
    }
    return null;
  },
  builder: (FormFieldState formFieldState) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Row(
          children: [
            Checkbox(
              value: agreedToTerms,
              onChanged: (value) {
                // When the value of the checkbox changes,
                // update the FormFieldState so the form is
                // re-validated.
                formFieldState.didChange(value);
                setState(() {
                  agreedToTerms = value;
                });
              },
            ),
            Text(
              'I agree to the terms of service.',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1,
            ),
          ],
        ),
        if (!formFieldState.isValid)
          Text(
            formFieldState.errorText ?? "",
            style: Theme.of(context)
                .textTheme
                .caption
                .copyWith(color: Theme.of(context).errorColor),
          ),
      ],
    );
  },
),
```

**Rule of thumb**: If your box only have a single input field, just use the raw material input like `TextField` (`FormField` is a bit overkill in this case though). If your box has many input fields, you need to wrap each one of them in a `FormField`, and then integrate all of them to the `Form` widget to reap the benefits of validating and saving all form fields at once.

**Extra tip**: If u have a `TextField` wrapped in a `FormField` that doesn't allow the user to enter any text such as a `CupertinoPickerFormField` or a `SimpleDialogFormField` that offers the user a choice between several options (which is basically a material `SimpleDialog` widget wrapped in a `FormField`), just simply use the `hintText` param of `InputDecoration` without using  `TextEditingController` to manipulate text. Make the hint text have the same color as the normal input text with `hintStyle: const TextStyle(color: Color(0xdd000000))`.

This [video from Flutter Europe](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W3rilPv69lM) will help you master forms in Flutter in no time.