# Flutter TextField vs TextFormField

Tags: android, flutter, dart, textfield, textformfield

What is the difference between TextField and TextFormField in flutter? Both look the same.  Which one should i use? Which one do you recommend? I use TextField like this:

```
const TextField(
  obscureText: true,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
    labelText: 'Password',
  ),
)
```

Comment: You can look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54664507/9661936). But in short, if you want to validate the input from user, use TextFormField.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between TextFormField and TextField?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54661567/what-is-the-difference-between-textformfield-and-textfield)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `TextFormField` mainly has the `validator` argument, while `TextField` doesn't: it must return `null` if the input is valid, and it must return a `String` if there's some error (usually the `String` itself contains information about the error). This argument allows you to validate the user input in a very easy way, provided that you include the form fields (there are others, in addition to `TextFormField`) in a `Form` widget and that you apply a `Key` to the `Form`.

If you do everything correctly, you could just invoke `formKey.currentState!.validate()` and automatically Flutter will invoke the `validator` argument for each form field that you added to the `Form`. If everything checks, the `validate` will return `true`, and you can proceed with your program logic. Otherwise, it will return `false` and it will show the `String` returned by the `validator` near the form field that contained incorrect data.

This example is taken from the [Flutter cookbook](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/forms/validation) on forms:

```
[...]
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Build a Form widget using the _formKey created above.
    return Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          TextFormField(
            // The validator receives the text that the user has entered.
            validator: (value) {
              if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                return 'Please enter some text';
              }
              return null;
            },
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
            child: ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                // Validate returns true if the form is valid, or false otherwise.
                if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                    const SnackBar(content: Text('Processing Data')),
                  );
                }
              },
              child: const Text('Submit'),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You use TextFormField when using Form widget. Combined with Form widget you can make more complex forms + validation for whole form.

TextField is basically a TextFormField but you don't have to include it into the Form widget and validation would work a bit differently.